Do state level judges have the same authority as article III judges to enjoin a convicted party from exercising constitutional rights?
When a person is convicted of a crime in federal court (or when a person pleads guilty) an article III judge may enjoin the convicted party from exercising certain constitutional rights as a term of their probation, such as their right to travel, their right to bear arms, their right to free speech (sometimes), and their right to file lawsuits.
Please keep in mind that the type of enjoinment I am referring to is not by statute, which this enjoinment is imposed as a sentence for the crime the person has been convicted of committing, but rather a term that the person agrees to as a condition of their probation.
While the type of enjoinment that can be imposed is not unlimited and must be related to the crime that was committed, it is quite extensive, and certainly oversteps the bounds of what would be acceptably imposed on a person who has not been convicted, or what can be imposed by a person who is not an article III judge such as an article II executive officer.
My question is if state level judges who are not article III judges have the right to exercise this same authority or if their ability to enjoin convicted persons is different or less broad

I think "or when a person pleads guilty" is redundant. If they plead guilty, they're convicted.


When a person is convicted of a crime in federal court (or when a
person pleads guilty) an article III judge may enjoin the convicted
party from exercising certain constitutional rights as a term of their
probation, such as their right to travel, their right to bear arms,
their right to free speech (sometimes), and their right to file
lawsuits.
Please keep in mind that the type of enjoinment I am referring to is
not by statute, which this enjoinment is imposed as a sentence for the
crime the person has been convicted of committing, but rather a term
that the person agrees to as a condition of their probation . . .
My question is if state level judges who are not article III judges
have the right to exercise this same authority or if their ability to
enjoin convicted persons is different or less broad?

Short Answer
The statutory authority of judges in criminal cases to impose bond conditions in federal court differs slightly due to differences in federal and state criminal sentencing and criminal procedure statutes and court rules and standing orders. But the differences are not material or significant in the vast majority of cases.
This is also largely true with respect to conditions imposed as part of a criminal probation sentence imposed following the conviction of a criminal defendant.
Long Answer
Probations v. Bond Conditions
First, a point of terminology, "probation" is one possible sentence that can be imposed for certain crimes, in lieu of incarceration, but possibly in addition to fines and restitution and the collateral effects of a conviction. Sometimes probation is agreed to as part of a criminal sentence, but in all cases, whether or not agreed to, probation and the associated conditions of probation are ordered by the court.
If the conditions of probation are agreed to as part of a plea agreement, any right to appeal or contest those conditions of probation are typically waived.
Probation is not the correct term to apply to conditions imposed upon someone pending trial in a criminal case, pending sentencing of a convicted criminal defendant, or pending an appeal during which the enforcement of a sentence imposed by the court is stayed in the discretion of the court.
The exact label to these three distinct circumstances under which a criminal defendant is not incarcerated prior to a criminal conviction and sentence becoming a final order varies slightly from one court system (e.g., the federal courts, or the courts of a particular state) to another. But, I will call them what I believe to be the most common label, which is "bond conditions."
While the quoted language from the question isn't entirely clear (and often the same government officials who supervise convicted criminal defendants on probation also supervise criminal defendants while released pursuant to bond conditions), I believe that the question is really asking about "bond conditions" and not "probation."
Federal v. State Judge Authority
Similarities
Subject to some very narrow exceptions, most of which are inapplicable to the examples given, there is no U.S. Constitutional prohibition or federal law limitation on the ability of a state law judge to impose restrictions on constitutional rights as part of bond conditions or conditions of a probation sentence that is not agreed to by a convicted criminal defendant.
The one constitutional right identified in the question which, absent highly specific findings that someone is an abusive litigant beyond a mere conviction or pending criminal case, cannot be imposed, is a prohibition on filing lawsuits, about pretty much anything, including collateral attacks on the criminal conviction in that particular case. Neither a state nor a federal judge can limit lawsuits about the reality of the way that the sentence imposed is conducted either (e.g., a convicted offender cannot be barred from filing lawsuits over a violation of their rights that is not authorized by court order or statute by a probation officer, e.g., sexual abuse of the defendant/convict by a probation officer).
Freedom to exercise one's religion is another right which cannot generally be unreasonably limited in either a bond condition, or in a probation condition, without the consent of the defendant (before or after conviction), without the consent of the person subject to the bond condition or probation condition.
While the differences are subtle, in general, a state or federal judge has a greater right to restrict the freedom of a defendant who is convicted of a crime in a probation sentence, than a state or federal judge has to restrict the freedom of a criminal defendant who has not yet been convicted of a crime in the case in a bond condition.
You would have to ask a specialist in criminal law in a particular state or federal court system for examples of those distinctions.
But, the gist of the matter, is the bond conditions are limited to those that will cause a criminal defendant to behave and remain subject to the jurisdiction of the court while a case is pending, while a probation condition can, in theory, be more punitive (e.g. requiring community service).
Also, bond conditions often do end up being negotiated, because there is a tradeoff between the dollar amount of a bond that the judge feels is necessary to impose, and the extent to which the bond conditions are sufficiently restrictive that the judge doesn't feel the need to impose a high dollar amount of a cash bond. And, when it is negotiated and agreed to be the prosecutor, the defendant, and the judge, this generally can't be contested.
But since there is a constitutional right to have bond set for you in most cases, not all bond conditions are negotiated. And, in those cases, and in cases where the judge simply imposes bond conditions without receiving meaningful proposals from the prosecutor or the defendant (which is the norm in low stakes minor criminal cases) unlawful bond conditions can be challenged in an appellate court.
The lion's share of conditions that can't be imposed by federal judges also cannot be imposed by state judges, and vice versa.
Differences
The bond conditions and probation conditions imposed by a federal judge have to be authorized by a federal criminal statute (normally, United States Code Title 18), but usually this afford federal judges very broad discretion to impose bond conditions and upon conviction, probation conditions. These conditions are subject to appellate review only for an abuse of discretion by the judge if they are colorably authorized by law.
The bond conditions and probation conditions imposed by a state judge in a state criminal case have to be authorized by a state criminal statute (or the state constitution, or state common law) from the state where the judge is presiding. But, again, usually this afford federal judges very broad discretion to impose bond conditions and upon conviction, probation conditions. These conditions are subject to appellate review only for an abuse of discretion by the judge if they are colorably authorized by law.
There is a relatively recent trend for some states to impose minimum boilerplate conditions, either as a matter of state statute or court rule or an official court policy, as part of every set of bond conditions. There is likewise a relatively recent trend for some states to impose minimum boilerplate conditions (usually more restrictive ones), either as a matter of state statute or court rule or an official court policy, as part of every sentence of probation that is imposed.
Many of these new requirements are not formally present in federal criminal cases, although often the bond conditions and probation conditions imposed in federal cases are boilerplate terms that are the same in almost every criminal case because that is how federal judges choose to exercise their discretion, or under a policy or local rule, or standard form, of that particular court. And, in practice the standard conditions in federal court are quite similar to the standard conditions in state court.
So, there are subtle differences in what bond conditions or what probation conditions may be, or must be imposed, by judges in criminal cases in the federal courts, or in any particular state court, that arise from differences between federal criminal statutes and criminal procedure rules, and state criminal statutes and criminal procedure rules. But, these differences don't consistently give federal judges more power than state judges, nor do they consistently give state judges more power than federal judges.
In practice, while it is possible for there to be significant differences between the power of a federal judge to impose bond conditions, or to impose probation conditions, and the power of a state judge to impose bond conditions, or to impose probate conditions, there are rarely any material differences in the authority of federal judges in criminal cases, and state judges in criminal cases.
Collateral consequences of a conviction compared
There are also some offenses where any criminal conviction, state or federal, of a certain kind of offense, has collateral consequences which are automatic upon conviction, like prohibiting the person convicted from possessing a firearm, or making the convicted defendant eligible for deportation, which arise under federal statutes and are outside the discretion of either a state judge or a federal judge in a criminal case.
In some states, conviction of certain kinds of offenses, usually felonies, broadly defined, disqualifies the convicted defendant from voting in elections or running for state and local office, and disqualifies the person from being licensed in certain occupations. In essentially every state except Maine, this is true until the sentence for the crime is fully served. In a shrinking minority of states, these limitations are permanent for elections held in the state with the prohibition. Exactly when the prohibitions on voting and being licensed in certain occupations starts (e.g. upon conviction, or only upon the conviction becoming final with no remaining direct appeals), and when it ends (e.g. during a post-release from prison period of "parole" or until all fines and restitution awards are paid in full) can be tricky technical questions that vary in detail from one state to another.
In general, however, one state cannot prohibit voting or running for office in another state as a collateral consequence of a criminal conviction in the first state.
For example, Alabama can't bar people convicted of a felony in Alabama from voting in elections or running for office in Maine, as a collateral consequence of an Alabama criminal conviction. But, Alabama can bar people convicted of a felony in Maine from voting or running for office in Alabama as a collateral consequence of a non-Alabama criminal conviction.
Caveat
This answer summarizes, in general terms, the law in the federal system, 50 states, and multiple U.S. jurisdictions outside of any state. There are hundreds if not thousands of pages of statutes and court rules and directives, and hundreds if not thousands of precedent creating cases that spell this out in more detail and may  differ somewhat from the general rule. I've tried to briefly discuss the most notable general rules and the most notable exceptions to the general rules.

People on parole are under arrest and their rights are already enjoined. It doesn't matter whether the arrest is under State or Federal authority. See for example gag orders against Trump issued by the NY State judge. There's nothing in the Article III of the US constitution to reserve that right to Federal judges specifically.

My question is if state level judges who are not article III judges have the right to exercise this same authority or if their ability to enjoin convicted persons is different or less broad

As said, Article III is not the authority, the State and Federal law is. As such the State judges' authority is derived from their respective State law, while the Federal judges' authority is derived from the Federal law. While specifics may differ between states, the general principles are the same.

This doesn't answer the question at all.

ok, better now? Feel free to add your own answer.

I've corrected my question to use the word "probation" instead of "parole". That was my mistake

@littleadv Not really. As edited, the answer can essentially be distilled down to a single sentence: "It depends on what the law says," which doesn't really provide any useful information.

Also, Article III judges definitely have authority that executive officers don't have, as delegated to them by both article III and other parts of the constitution. This includes issuing warrants, sentencing people, setting bail, and determining guilt based on the law.

@littleadv The answer could likely be improved by focusing on an actual jurisdiction, looking at the actual law of that jurisdiction, disclosing what that law says, and then discussing how that law answers OP's question.

@Badasahog where? Article III

@littleadv the due process clause of the 14th amendment, as well as the due process clause of the 5th amendment

@Badasahog neither mention any of the concepts you claim. All come from law/precedent.

@littleadv executive authorities aren't allowed enjoin a party from selling books which violate obscenity law, thus depriving them of liberty. Judges can, because they can make a legal determination of whether or not those books violate the law. (Bantam Books, Inc. v. Sullivan (1963))

@Badasahog but then... the legislature made the law, and the executive branch enforces that decision, doesn't it? I can turn it around all you want.

the legislature is prohibited from enforcing certain laws unless a judge grants them permission to do so at each application. This includes laws which implicates first amendment rights

@Badasahog the legislature is prohibited from enforcing certain laws unless a judge grants them permission to do so at each application - huh?

@Badasahog Judges don't proactively review laws. They can only declare a law unconstitutional if someone is convicted under the law and appeals the conviction.

@Barmar if a person is speeding or driving recklessly, a police officer has the right to arrest them. If a person sells a book which violates obscenity law, that person cannot be stopped from doing so until a court rules that they violated the law. generally (with some exceptions)

@Badasahog How does it get before a judge if no one tries to enforce the law?

@Barmar the enforcers go to the judge, just like they would if they wanted a search warrant

You wrote "the legislature is prohibited", that's why I thought you were referring to creating the laws. The police are part of the executive. @Badasahog
